# Extract day of the week and hour from iso datetime stamp in Python

Tags: python, datetime, isodate

How can I extract the day of the week and the hour of the day from a timestamp in this format?

```
2020-08-17T01:54:38.000Z
```

So for the example above I would get Monday and 01 in return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could parse the string into a [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) object using [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) with a custom format, and then extract the info you need from it:

```py
from datetime import datetime
dateStr = '2020-08-17T01:54:38.000Z'
dt = datetime.strptime(dateStr,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
hour = dt.strftime('%H')
dayOfWeek = dt.strftime('%A')
```

Comment: I got this error: ValueError: time data '2020-08-17T01:54:48.504Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z'

Comment: @hokoio sorry, I missed the millisecond part. Edited and fixed.

Comment: sorry i didn't mention in my question. Is there anyway that the hour can return 01, 02, 03 instead of just 1, 2 or 3?

Comment: @hokoio sure - you can format it with `strftime` - see my edited answer